# how to set TabIndex for jquery combobox?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui

How can I set TabIndex for jquery combobox?
If I set tabindex for dropdown listbox it doesn't set for jquery comobox. how to do it?

this is my dropdown:

```
  <asp:DropDownList ID="DrpCountryName" runat="server" Width="138px">
                        </asp:DropDownList>
```

jquery code:

```
  $(function() {
        $("#DrpCountryName").combobox();
        $("#toggle").click(function() {
            $("#DrpCountryName").toggle();
        });
```

**Edit:**
as you know jquery combobox hides the `dropdown` and creates an `input` and a `button` and fill it with the values of `dropdown`. so I should set `tabindex` for input instead of `dropdown`. how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using ASP.NET and you want to use the ID, then you'll have to play with the ClientIDMode property (unique to asp.net) to get the correct ID.

However, I just added a class attribute to the control in order to easily reference it and then wrote the jquery like this:

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{
    $('.DrpCountryName .ui-combobox-input').attr("tabindex", 6);
});
```

The .ui-combobox-input is the class that you'll want to set the tabindex on since that's the text input. You'll need that css class prefix if there's more than one jquery combobox on the page.

Answer (score 0):

When your page renders, the ID of your `DropDownList` (`<select>`) will not be "DrpCountryName", it will be mangled to include the naming containers in which it exists, so something like: "ctl00_Panel_DrpCountryName".

You should change your JavaScript to:

```
$("#<%= DrpCountryName.ClientID %>").combobox();
```

Or

```
$("select[name*='DrpCountryName']").combobox(); // contains "DrpCountryName"
$("select[name$='DrpCountryname']").combobox(); // ends with "DrpCountryName"
```

The first one will render the actual client ID of the `DropDownList` into the jQuery selector. The second will find the `<select>` list with a name that contains or ends with "DrpCountryName". Either should be fine, though the first is a hair faster.

If you "View Source" of your page after it's rendered, you can see what the ID and Name attributes are.

Comment: Yeah I know about it. my question is about `tabindex`. `jquery combobox` hides the dropdown and create an `input` and a `button` and fill it with the values of dropdown. so I should set tabindex for `input` instead of dropdown. how to do it?